# Equivalente en Linq a limmit y offset en Sql

Tags: sql, linq

Cómo podría limitar los resultados y establecer un punto de partida en una sentencia de linq?

```
var clientes = from c in _context.clientes where c.edad > 18 orderby c.nombre select c;
```

Gracias de antemano. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando Linq tenes los métodos de extensión [`Enumerable.Skip`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skip?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.Linq.Enumerable.Skip%60%601);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8) y [`Enumerable.Take`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DES-ES%26k%3Dk(System.Linq.Enumerable.Take%60%601);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.8), donde el primero, lo usarás para omitir n elementos, y el segundo, para definir cuantos elementos deseas obtener.

Por lo que en tu caso particular, sería algo como lo siguiente

```
var clientes = (from c in _context.clientes where c.edad > 18 orderby c.nombre select c).Skip(4).Take(10);
```

En el ejemplo anterior, ignorarás los primeros 4 elementos, y tomarás los siguientes 10.